# Prove $\frac{1}{x \log(x)}$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[2, \infty]$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Not sure how to proceed on this one. The function is clearly measurable so the issue has to be divergence of the integral. However any comparison seems to fail. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Do you know an antiderivative of $1/(x \ln x)$?

Comment: No! So one has to evaluate the integral directly?

Comment: I don't know that one "has to", but certainly one *can*.

Comment: @EricTowers Thanks! What else could one try?

Comment: When you see $\log x$ in there, try the substitution $e^u = x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to totally give it away, but take the derivative of $\log( \log(x))$

Comment: Thanks! I see how it works now!